# TypeScript JQuery interface merging needs to reference module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm having trouble finding good guidance on how to layout d.ts files for my modules.

Compiling to target ES5 and CommonJS modules.

I have a remote.ts file that exports both a class Remote and an interface IRemoteOptions.

```
//remote.ts
export class Remote {
 //...
}
export interface IRemoteOptions{
  ///...
}
```

I then extend JQuery to add a function `remote(options?: IRemoteOptions`).

```
//global.d.ts
interface JQuery{
 remote(options? IRemoteOptions);
}
```

How do I make sure that global.d.ts knows about `IRemoteOptions` without adding an import statement to that file? If I add an import statement, it becomes a module itself and ruins the scope for extending `JQuery`.

We have a number of other extension points to JQuery that'll need to be added, what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working using the Global Augmentation method.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation

I moved the JQuery interface extension back into my remote.ts file like this:

```
//remote.ts
export class Remote {
 //...
}
export interface IRemoteOptions{
  ///...
}
declare global{
  interface JQuery{
    remote(options? IRemoteOptions);
  }
}
```